# Detect movement of UIView inside another UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, key-value-observing

**What I have:**

When I move a `UIView` I am detecting its movement by doing the following:

```
[myView.layer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"position" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

Being `myView` the `UIView` I am moving and `self` a class I have to detect the different positions the `UIView` has.

**The Issue:**

When I put `myView` inside another `UIView` and I move the `anotherView`:

```
[anotherView addSubview: myView];
```

The method:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context;
```

Is not called anymore, although in theory `myView` is moving as well. I tried to use `NSNotification` to be fired  every time a "movement" occurred, but I find it clumsy. Is there an "elegant" solution for this kind of problem?

---

For the movement of the `UIView` I am using this methods:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

Comment: Did the solution posted below ever work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have uploaded a sample project here that does this cleanly:

https://github.com/n9986/ObservingUIViewMovement

I had a similar requirement sometime back. The issue here is that when you add the UIView to another UIView (call it superView), it now resides in the coordinate space of superView. Therefore, the movement of superView in it's parent's coordinate space does not effect it's children.

I will explain the code here a bit.

We have `ViewController`, `MyView` and `InsideView` classes illustrating your typical classes. I want to observe in the viewController whether the InsideView has moved or not. So in the custom class, I added a property `positionInWindow` and updated it whenever the superView moved.

So in `InsideView.m`:

```
// Make sure this property exists in .h file to make the class KVC compliant
@synthesize positionInWindow;

// This method is called when the super view changes.
- (void)didMoveToSuperview
{
    // Drop a random log message
    NSLog(@"MAI SUPERVIEW HAS CHANGED!!!");

    // Start observing superview's frame
    [self addObserver:self 
           forKeyPath:@"superview.frame" 
              options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
              context:nil];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                      ofObject:(id)object 
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change 
                       context:(void *)context
{
    // Here we update the positionInWindow because 
    // we know the superView.frame has changed
    CGPoint frameOrigin = self.frame.origin;
    [self setPositionInWindow:[[self window] convertPoint:frameOrigin
                                                 fromView:self]];
}
```

And anywhere you want to monitor this view:

```
// On an instance of InsideView
[insideView addObserver:self 
             forKeyPath:@"positionInWindow" 
                options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
                context:nil];
```

The good part about this solution is that `InsideView` does not need to know who is it's `superView`. This code will work even if the `superView` is later changed. There is no modification to the `MyView` class. And any class can monitor it's property independent of that fact.

Comment: What happens if superview.superview.frame has changed? So this will only detect changes to the immediate superview, but what about the rest of the hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, UIView's don't move "on their own", which means you probably have some code around there for the movement

Maybe try setting some delegate or notification there instead of using addObserver:

Comment: in touchesMoved, are you doing something like "myView.frame = ..."? that's what you're after

Comment: The movement of the `UIView` is fine... I just want to know (KVO) when the `UIView` is inside another `UIView` and it is moving...

Comment: Who makes it move when it goes into another view?